# Serialize an array of object which is an attribute of an another object with symfony4 serializer

Tags: symfony, angular7

I have an entity called Vente this entity is related to an other called VenteAdd with the relation ManyToOne (One Vente have One or Many VenteAdd and each VenteAdd is related only To one Vente) in the vente entity class the property venteAdd is declared as an Entity venteAdd as usual by Doctrine and in the constructor the venteAdd entity is initialzed as an ArrayCollection. when the angular 7 client send the Vente entity the attribute ventAdd is an array of VenteAdd when i try to deserialize the entity vente with symfony serializer i have the error

> Failed to denormalize attribute "_vente_add" value for class
>   "App\Entity\Vente": Expected argument of type "App\Entity\VenteAdd",
>   "array" given at property path "_vente_add"

I have a set and a get venteAdd functions in my vente entity and the parameters are Collection 
Can someone help me please
my code : VenteController

```
$data = $request->getContent();
$data = $this->nativeSerializer->deserialize($data,'App\Entity\Vente', 'json');
```

initialisation of the serializer in the venteContoller constructor:

```
 $dateCallback = function ($innerObject, $outerObject, string $attributeName, string $format = null, array $context = []) {
            return $innerObject instanceof \DateTime ? $innerObject->format(\DateTime::ISO8601) : '';
        };
        $defaultContext = [
            AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object, $format, $context) {
                return $object->getId();
            },
            AbstractNormalizer::CALLBACKS => [
                'dateVente' => $dateCallback,
                'dateEntree'=>$dateCallback,
            ],
        ];
        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null,null,null,null,null,null,$defaultContext);
        $this->nativeSerializer = new Serializer([$normalizer,new ArrayDenormalizer()], [new JsonEncoder()]);
```

the Vente entity

doctrine Declaration:

```
 /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\VenteAdd", mappedBy="vente")
    */
    private $VenteAdd;
```

constructor:

```
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->VenteAdd = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

getter and Setter:

```
/**
 * @return Collection|VenteAdd[]
 */
public function getVenteAdd(): Collection
{
    return $this->VenteAdd;
}

/**
  * @param Collection|VenteAdd[]
  * @return self
 */
public function setVenteAdd(ArrayCollection $venteAdd): self
{
    $this->VenteAdd = $venteAdd;
    return $this;
}
```

please help me thanks...